# Create Blocks of containers which can scroll both horizontally and vertically in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview, dart, gridview

I am designing the app in which i have to create some number of blocks which represent the flats of building.
in which i have 2 numbers

- number of floors
- number of flats per floor

so i tried 2 ways

1. Using gridview and give `itemCount` as number of floors `crossAxisCount` as - number of flats per floor
2. Using 2 Listview. first listview for floor - which scroll vertically and inside its builder second listview for flats which scroll horizontally.

but i want to make it as scrollable for both horizontally and vertically, so i don't know how to do it, can anyone help me please !
[look this,created using listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFKrP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by nesting horizontal `ListViews` inside a vertical `ListView`:

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemExtent: 50,
  itemBuilder: (context, verticalIndex) => ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 15,
    itemExtent: 50,
    itemBuilder: (context, appartmentIndex) => Container(),
  ),
);
```

---

#### Full Demo

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

const List<Color> kColors = [
  Color(0x66a7414a),
  Color(0x66282726),
  Color(0x666a8a82),
  Color(0x66a37c27),
  Color(0x66563838),
];
const double kOpacity = .6;
const double kAppartmentSize = 64.0;
const TextStyle kFloorTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 8.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
);
const TextStyle kApartmentTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 12.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
);
const int kMinNbFloors = 10;
const int kMaxNbFloors = 18;
const int kMinNbApartments = 3;
const int kMaxNbApartments = 10;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Real Estate Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Real Estate Demo')),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  final Random random = new Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final nbFloors = useState(
        kMinNbFloors + random.nextInt(kMaxNbFloors - kMinNbFloors + 1));
    final nbAppartments = useState(
      List.generate(
        nbFloors.value,
        (index) =>
            kMinNbApartments +
            random.nextInt(kMaxNbApartments - kMinNbApartments + 1),
      ),
    );
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: nbFloors.value,
      itemExtent: kAppartmentSize,
      reverse: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, floorIndex) => ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: nbAppartments.value[floorIndex],
        itemExtent: kAppartmentSize,
        itemBuilder: (context, appartmentIndex) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:
                kColors[random.nextInt(kColors.length)].withOpacity(kOpacity),
            border: Border.all(
              width: .5, // red as border color
            ),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/window.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(appartmentIndex.toString(), style: kApartmentTextStyle),
                const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                Text(floorIndex.toString(), style: kFloorTextStyle),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, But i already tried this code. so vertical scrolling is working properly but for horizontal scroll it should scroll whole screen. I means it should not scroll only one row. It should scroll all rows together! (like in paytm seat booking view for movie)

Comment: @chiragmevada did you ever find a solution scrolling in two directions simultaniously ?