# how to use multi scroll in one screen -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to create an web ui in flutter like trello in that I want one horizontal primary scroll and one vertical secondary scroll but I am not able to scroll vertically in column I attach what I want to create and my code and if you still not understand please let me know

[image]

Here is my code :-

```
class PlaningWeekScreenWeb extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaningWeekScreenWeb({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // Use this for set width of card and row in list
  final double cardWidth = 180.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: _getSideMenu()),
        Container(
          height: Get.height,
          width: 1,
          color: scrollBarColor,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: _getMainScreen(),
          flex: 6,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _getMainScreen() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: cardWidth,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          (10.0).addWSpace(),
                          "29".h3(
                              size: 25,
                              weight: FontWeight.w700,
                              color: GrayColor),
                          (5.0).addWSpace(),
                          Expanded(
                              child: "Sun".h3(
                                  color: GrayColor,
                                  weight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  size: 15)),
                          (10.0).addWSpace(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: scrollBarColor,
                      height: 1,
                      width: cardWidth,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: cardWidth,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            primary: false,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                                PlaningWeekCard(
                                  device: Device.Web,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  width: cardWidth,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: Get.height,
                            width: 1,
                            color: scrollBarColor,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _getSideMenu() {
    return Container(
      height: Get.height,
      // width: 220,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            "Employers".h3(weight: FontWeight.w700, size: 22),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            PerytonSearchField(
              hintText: 'Name',
            ),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  PerytonCheckBox(val: false),
                  (5.0).addWSpace(),
                  Expanded(child: "Codonnier Offieces".expansionTileTittleWeb())
                ],
              ),
              children: [
                _getRow("Norway office"),
                _getRow("Surat office"),
                _getRow("Bardoli office"),
                _getRow("Usa office"),
              ],
            ),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  PerytonCheckBox(val: false),
                  (5.0).addWSpace(),
                  Expanded(child: "Codonnier Branches".expansionTileTittleWeb())
                ],
              ),
              children: [
                _getRow("Amsterdam office"),
                _getRow("Surat office"),
                _getRow("Suart-6 office"),
                _getRow("california office"),
              ],
            ),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  PerytonCheckBox(val: false),
                  (5.0).addWSpace(),
                  Expanded(
                      child: "Codonnier sub branches".expansionTileTittleWeb())
                ],
              ),
              children: [
                _getRow("van gogh branch"),
                _getRow("Mota varacha branch"),
                _getRow("vesu branch"),
                _getRow("san francisco office"),
              ],
            ),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            "Workers".h3(weight: FontWeight.w700, size: 22),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            PerytonSearchField(
              hintText: 'Name',
            ),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            _getRow("Harsh codonnier"),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            _getRow("Dipak codonnier"),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            _getRow("Subham codonnier"),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
            _getRow("ravi codonnier"),
            (10.0).addHSpace(),
          ],
        ).pSymmetricOnly(horizontal: 10),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getRow(String name) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        PerytonCheckBox(val: false),
        (5.0).addWSpace(),
        Expanded(child: name.expansionTileWeb())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my card widget:-

```
class PlaningDayCard extends StatelessWidget {
  PlaningDayCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.device,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.width})
      : super(key: key);
  final Device device;
  final double width;
  final Function onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveWidget(
        mobile: _getMobileCard(),
        tablet: _getWebCard(),
        desktop: _getWebCard(),
        device: device);
  }

  Widget _getWebCard() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width - 2,
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                onTap.call();
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: "Scrubbing sinks, tubs, showers"
                            .h2(weight: FontWeight.w700, size: 15),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  (6.0).addHSpace(),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ImageAssetIconWithColor(
                        color: GrayColor,
                        size: 15,
                        image: ImageIcons.icTriangle,
                      ),
                      (8.0).addWSpace(),
                      Expanded(
                        child: "Main Office".h2(
                            weight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: GrayColor,
                            size: 14),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  (8.0).addWSpace(),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      "09:00—13:00".h2(
                          weight: FontWeight.w700, color: GrayColor, size: 13),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ).pSymmetricOnly(vertical: 5, horizontal: 6),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _getMobileCard() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width - 2,
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.sp),
          ),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.sp),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                onTap.call();
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of code depending on 3rd party packages, can you simplify the code snippet ?

Comment: no it not depend on third party package I use extension and custom widgets that's what it loot like this and I am not able to share all code here

Comment: Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Complete Tested Code**

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TrelloExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrelloExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrelloExample> createState() => _TrelloExampleState();
}

class _TrelloExampleState extends State<TrelloExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 64.0),
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
           behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
            dragDevices: {
              PointerDeviceKind.touch,
              PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
            },
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: List.generate(
                16,
                (index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 16.0, left: index == 0 ? 16.0 : 0.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: List.generate(
                        index % 2 == 1
                            ? 16
                            : index % 3 == 1
                                ? 8
                                : index % 1 == 1
                                    ? 4
                                    : 6,
                        (index) => Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
                              color: Color(
                                      (Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                                  .withOpacity(1.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Trello Ticket Item $index",
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]**Complete Running Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
                height: 200,
                child: GridView.count(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  crossAxisCount: 1 ,
                  children: List.generate(50,(index){
                    return Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                   )
                  ],
                ),
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                    );

                  }),
                ),
              )         ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output View]

> You can achieve this with more than one ways. But I think the simplest way is that make `Row` as parent widget put all the `ListView` in `Row` after wrapping every `ListView` by `Expanded` widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: 10,
            controller: ScrollController(),
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(height: 10),
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            controller: ScrollController(),
            itemCount: 2,
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(height: 10),
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                )),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            controller: ScrollController(),
            itemCount: 6,
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(height: 10),
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.green,
                )),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with `SingleChildScrollView` over every page you want to scroll.
And also mention the `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`.

I hope it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First must wrap it with a single scroll child view.
2. Then wrap it in rows,
3. Then wrap it in a ListView
4. Use expanded so everything can be seen.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
class myScroll extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
@override
Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
PointerDeviceKind.touch,
PointerDeviceKind.mouse,

};
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Also, this question was already answered. What are you doing that's different? Why? Adding that as part of your explanation would be useful.